# Using the Elastic Olivere package (v5), how can I effectively query for values containing numbers and/or and other special characters?

Tags: elasticsearch, go

Using the example of an email, abc123@domain.com, how can I format a query to retrieve a document containing it? Currently, my query can return information pertaining to strings strictly containing letters; however, there are 0 total hits whenever non-letters are used.

ES has a token delimiter, but how can it be implemented via the Elastic golang package?